# Login used for multiple domains laravel

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel, multiple-domains

I'm working on project where users can park their own domain to the main site and then it redirects to user profile. Something like personal site.

```
masterdomain.com
masterdomain.com/username1
usersdomain.com == masterdomain.com/username1
```

And basically every user can do such domain redirect and create their site.

In project users can follow, chat, comment and do other things while logged in.
**Problem is, that login is related to particular domain name, so if I go to another user or to masterdomain.com I loose session...**

Is this even possible to solve and if so, how it could be done? Maybe it's possible to set cookie for IP address?